# Extract same elements chunk from list after instance of a particular element

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to extract the sequential 'NN' elements (including 'NNP') from a list and append to a new list given 'IN' or 'TO' are encountered before 'NN'. How can I do it?

I tried the following code. But unable to capture the  other similar instances.

```
    new = ['JJ',
 'NN',
 'IN',
 'NNP',
 'NN',
 'MD',
 'VB',
 'VBN',
 'IN',
 'NN',
 'TO',
 'VB',
 'NN',
 'CC',
 'NN',
 'TO',
 'NNP',
 'NN',
 'NN',
 '.']

lst = []
for i,j in enumerate(new):
    lst1 = []
    if j == 'IN':
        for i in new[i+1:]:
            if 'NN' in i:
                lst1.append(i)
                lst.append(lst1)
                break

lst = [['NNP'], ['NN']]
```

But I want to improve the code to give the below output:

```
[['NNP', 'NN'], ['NN'], ['NNP', 'NN', 'NN']
```

Each output chunk has either 'IN' or 'TO' occurred before them.

Actually, the above list (new) is underlying parts of speech for this list :

```
[['Additional',
  'condition',
  'of',
  'DeNOx',
  'activation',
  'shall',
  'be',
  'introduced',
  'in',
  'order',
  'to',
  'provide',
  'flexibility',
  'and',
  'robustness',
  'to',
  'NSC',
  'regeneration',
  'management',
  '.'],
 ['JJ',
  'NN',
  'IN',
  'NNP',
  'NN',
  'MD',
  'VB',
  'VBN',
  'IN',
  'NN',
  'TO',
  'VB',
  'NN',
  'CC',
  'NN',
  'TO',
  'NNP',
  'NN',
  'NN',
  '.']].
```

How can I map the results back to this list so that I will get

```
[['DeNOx', 'activation'], ['order'], ['NSC', 'regeneration', 'management']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not too far away. One way to make this easier is to obtain all the indexes of `'IN'` and `'TO'`:

```
starts = {'IN', 'TO'}
in_twos = [i for i, e in enumerate(new) if e in starts]
```

Which gives:

```
[2, 8, 10, 15]
```

Then you just need to iterate though these indexes, specifically `new[i+1:]`, and take elements that are `'NN'` or `'NNP'`. When you reach an element that is not one of these, `break` out of the loop.

Here is an example:

```
result = []
take = {'NN', 'NNP'}

for i in in_twos:
    temp = []
    for x in new[i+1:]:
        if x not in take:
            break

        temp.append(x)

    # If this is empty, don't add it
    if temp:
        result.append(temp)

print(result)
```

Which in the end outputs:

```
[['NNP', 'NN'], ['NN'], ['NNP', 'NN', 'NN']]
```

Another shorter way, as @schwobaseggl suggested, is to use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to make the extraction of `'NN'` elements easier. This function basically keeps extracting elements until the first argument predicate returns false.

Here is what it can look like:

```
from itertools import takewhile

# new, take and in_twos same as before

result = [l for l in [list(takewhile(lambda x: x in take, new[i+1:])) for i in in_twos] if l]

print(result)
# [['NNP', 'NN'], ['NN'], ['NNP', 'NN', 'NN']]
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to map the words and speeches together, you can do this:

```
new = [['JJ', 'NN', 'IN','NNP','NN','MD','VB','VBN','IN','NN','TO','VB','NN','CC','NN','TO','NNP','NN','NN','.'],
   ['Additional','condition','of','DeNOx','activation','shall','be','introduced','in', 'order','to','provide','flexibility','and','robustness', 'to','NSC','regeneration','management','.']]

starts = {'IN', 'TO'}
in_twos = [i for i, e in enumerate(new[0]) if e in starts]

speech = []
words = []
take = {'NN', 'NNP'}

for i in in_twos:
    temp = []
    for x, y in zip(new[0][i+1:], new[1][i+1:]):
        if x not in take:
            break

        temp.append((x, y))

    # If this is empty, don't add it
    if temp:
        speech.append([x for x, _ in temp])
        words.append([y for _, y in temp])

print(speech)
print(words)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[['NNP', 'NN'], ['NN'], ['NNP', 'NN', 'NN']]
[['DeNOx', 'activation'], ['order'], ['NSC', 'regeneration', 'management']]
```

Comment: I added some changes to my question. Will be glad if you can provide a way to map the resultant parts of speech ('new' list) to the real English words list as mentioned in my question. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use two handy [**`itertools`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for this: [**`groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [**`takewhile`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import groupby, takewhile

nn = lambda x: x.startswith('NN')
to_in = lambda x: x in ('IN', 'TO')

list(filter(None, [list(takewhile(nn, g)) for k, g in groupby(new, key=to_in)][1:]))
# [['NNP', 'NN'], ['NN'], ['NNP', 'NN', 'NN']]
```

This chunks the initial list in chunks based on the items being `TO` or `IN`. From each of the chunks except the first (to avoid any initial `NNs`), this takes elements while they start with `NN`. Finally, it [filters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) out non-truthy (empty) lists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm unable to map the results to the original list. Will be of great help if any help regarding this is provided.

Answer (score 1):

There is another nice answer posted while I was typing this out -- this is a simple implementation without imports.

```
full_list = []

for x in range(0, len(new)):
    if 'NN' in new[x] and ('IN' in new[x-1] or 'TO' in new[x-1]):
        temp_list = [new[x]]
        temp_index = x+1
        while 'NN' in new[temp_index]:
            temp_list.append(new[temp_index])
            temp_index += 1
        full_list.append(temp_list)
```